# Keydown for special chars like öüä fires 2 times and ouputs char without ' ¨ '

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, keylistener

I have a very strange problem with special keys on Safari on Mac.

The context is a bit difficult to explain, so I'll just describe the problem and hope somebody has an idea or guessing, to point me in the right direction.

When I press a char like ö:

- In the textfield only o appears
- the keydown listener is executed 2 times. Once with the same keycode as o (in the case of ö), and again with keycode 0.
- I have attached both keydown and keypress listener. Only keydown is executed (for "normal" letters like o keypress is also executed).

Any ideas..?? Thanks in advance.

Ok, here's a part of the context to give some understanding:

- Doesn't appear in all Macs.
- Appears when using flash with iframe containing an editor. I attached the listeners both to to the whole page and the editor to see what's happening. The problem happens when input in flash textfield. The javascript listener on the page reacts and has the behaviour I described.

I think it's not relevant that it's a flash textfield, because I'm catching the events in Javascript before they go to flash, and there I can see this strange behaviour.

Comment: I edited the question title on the assumption that the double period (`..`) was meant to be a diaeresis or umlaut character: `¨`. If I'm wrong please feel free to roll-back the question. =)

Comment: It's right, thanks. I was just lazy =P

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue... JavaScript expects 16-bit characters. Maybe your character is encoded in a 32-bit value... (although umlauted characters all fit in 16-bit)

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate events could be a browser quirk, but in any case Keydown cannot be expected to give you the actual character that will be entered -- the keycode it provides merely identifies the key on the keyboard. What character (if any) will be input as a result depends on the keyboard layout, other key combinations (such as Shift or AltGr), and even prior key presses (in the case of "dead keys").

There's a lot of information on this at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: I know that keydown doesn't give the char, that's why I added keypress (where it's possible to use charCode), but that isn't triggered, as noted in my post. Thanks for the link, will read that asap.

Comment: ok, readed it. It helped me at least to understand why I'm not getting  any concrete answer here... anyways good article, the author did a lot of research and gives a great overview of all problems around key listeners...